# Can I still get Black Spindle?

Tags: destiny

So, I've found conflicting reports, and I'm honestly not sure which one is accurate. According to the [Destiny wikia](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Spindle), the Black Spindle can only be obtained when "Lost to Light" is the Daily Heroic. However, I found [another source](http://planetdestiny.com/black-spindle-guide/) saying it can be acquired at any time, simply by putting the mission on Heroic difficulty.

Which of these sources is correct? *Can* I get Black Spindle at any time, assuming I put together a fireteam to attempt it? Or is there no point in trying to assemble a team until it's the Daily Heroic?

Comment: The reason for the confusion is that before the June update, you could only obtain it when Lost to Light is the Daily Heroic. Since then, this mission (and any other timed missions to get exotics) have been unlocked so they are obtainable at any time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just load the mission on heroic from the director and follow the usual steps from when it was daily only.